# Alamofire issue can't use

Tags: swift3, xcode8, alamofire

I did everything but still not working ! as you see i cant use Alamofire keyword (i imported Alamofire , reinstall alamofire 4.4 also tried alamofire 3 ,also updated and double checked everything about cocoapods and everything installed correctly ) Im doing the course and Im stucked for 2 days  ..:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PROJECT NAME HERE' do
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'Alamofire',
    :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'swift3'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1.open Terminal and go to your project path (cd path)
2.Create Podfile using command "pod init"
3.Open pod file using "open Podfile" and add 
pod 'Alamofire',
    :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'swift3'
4. Run command "pod install"
5. open workspace and enjoy

Comment: i did this before did not worked out (i know hoe initial pods and cocoa pods ...)